# Multiple Image upload using AFNetworking Multipart form data not working

Tags: ios, swift, image-uploading, multipartform-data, afnetworking-2

I am trying to upload multiple images as multipart for data using AFNetworking  2.6.3 in my Swift project

Here is my code of appending data to form data

```
self.webserviceHandler.post(serviceName, parameters: nil, constructingBodyWith: { (data:AFMultipartFormData) in
                for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
                    let imagData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageArray[i], 0.5)
                    data.appendPart(withFileData: imagData!, name: "MenaImage[]", fileName: fileNameArray[i], mimeType: "image/jpeg")

                }

                for (key, value) in parameters{
                    data.appendPart(withForm: "\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, name: key as! String)
                }
            }, success: { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject:Any!) in
                successResponseClosure(responseObject as AnyObject)
            }) { (operation:AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error:Error!) in
                    errorClosure(error as NSError)
                }
```

webserviceHandler is AFHTTPRequestOperationManager shared class.

initialization of  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

```
init() {
        let baseURL = URL(string:"http://test.com/")!
        self.webserviceHandler = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager(baseURL:baseURL)
        self.webserviceHandler.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
        self.webserviceHandler.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()

        let contentType = NSString(string:"text/html")
        let contentTypes = NSMutableSet(set:self.webserviceHandler.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes!)
        if contentTypes.contains(contentType) == false{
            contentTypes.add(contentType)
            self.webserviceHandler.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = contentTypes as Set<NSObject>

        }
```

Here is the request logged by AFNetworkActivityLogger

```
{
    "Accept-Language" = "en-BH;q=1, ar-BH;q=0.9, en-GB;q=0.8";
    "Content-Length" = 3023913;
    "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+F955A845D801084F";
    "User-Agent" = "MBB/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 11.2.5; Scale/2.00)";
} (null)
```

Please help to fix this.

Comment: what's the error that it;s shown?

Comment: I have figured out the issue. I could upload images of size upto 100kb. When I try to upload images of size more than 100 kb, it fails. I dont think there is issue at server side because I could upload images of larger size from Postman. Is there any limit for size when using AFNetworking multipart formdata? I need to upload bigger images also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue. It was a problem at server side. There was code snippet to log the request receiving from apps. When the image there is large size image in request, this code throws error. When that code is removed its working perfectly. Hope this helps others also.